# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException:Unable to make field private javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.hgap

Tags: java, javafx, gson

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: 
Unable to make field private javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.hgap accessible: 
module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.scene.layout" to unnamed module @5cd04ad4.
```

I'm using a Gson library and when I want to serialized My class 'Bot' this error occured, I read something on internet about module and VM argument but nothing help me. Someone could help me?

this is my code:
class ControllerCreaPartita.java

```
package basic;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;

public class ControllerCreaPartita {
    //variabili di controllo
    int numeroCarteAGiocatore;
    final int lungCodicePartita=10;
    final int nViteDefault=5;
    Partita prt;
    Mazzo mazzo = new Mazzo();
    ArrayList<Giocatore> giocatoriPrt = new ArrayList<Giocatore>();
    String pathRetroCarta = "/basic/IMGcarte/retro.jpg";
    int countTurnoGiocatore=0;
    boolean dichiaraPrese=true;
    boolean primoTurno=true;
    String pathStatus = "src/Status.txt";
    String pathGiocatoriRegistrati = "src/GiocatoriRegistrati.txt";
    
    @FXML ListView<String> lstGiocatoriRegistrati;

    //aggiungo alla partita un nuovo utente  
    @FXML ListView<String> listUtentiPartita;
    @FXML Button btnAggiungiUtente;
    @FXML TextField txtNomeUtente; 
    @FXML public void AggiungiUtente(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String nome = txtNomeUtente.getText();
        //controllo che non vengano inseriti giocatori con lo stesso nome all'interno della listview listUtentiPartita
        if(!nome.trim().equals("") && !listUtentiPartita.getItems().contains(nome) && !lstGiocatoriRegistrati.getItems().contains(nome)) {
            txtNomeUtente.clear();
            listUtentiPartita.getItems().add(nome);
            lstGiocatoriRegistrati.getItems().add(nome);
            giocatoriPrt.add(new Giocatore(nome));
            
            try{

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(pathGiocatoriRegistrati, true);
                fw.write(nome + '\n');
                fw.close();
                
                } catch (FileNotFoundException FNFe) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    FNFe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException IOe) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    IOe.printStackTrace();
                }
        }else {
            txtNomeUtente.clear();
            
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Errore");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Il Nickname inserito è già stato selezionato da un altro giocatore, riprova con un altro Nickname");

            alert.showAndWait();
        }
        
    }
    
    //aggiungo alla partita un utente già registrato
    @FXML public void selezionaGiocatore(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        
        String nome = lstGiocatoriRegistrati.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();   
        
        if(!listUtentiPartita.getItems().contains(nome) && nome != null)
        {
            listUtentiPartita.getItems().add(nome);
            giocatoriPrt.add(new Giocatore(nome));  
        }
    }
    

    //aggiungo alla partita un utente robot 
    @FXML Button btnAggiungiUtenteRobot;
    @FXML TextField txtNomeUtenteRobot; 
    @FXML public void AggiungiUtenteRobot(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String nome = txtNomeUtenteRobot.getText();
        //controllo che non vengano inseriti giocatori con lo stesso nome all'interno della listview listUtentiPartita
        if(!nome.trim().equals("") && !listUtentiPartita.getItems().contains(nome) && !lstGiocatoriRegistrati.getItems().contains(nome)) {
            txtNomeUtenteRobot.clear();
            listUtentiPartita.getItems().add(nome);
            giocatoriPrt.add(new Bot(nome));
        }else {
            txtNomeUtenteRobot.clear();
        }
    }
    
    //Genero il codice per una nuova partita
    @FXML Button btnGeneraCodice;
    @FXML TextField txtCodice;
    @FXML ComboBox<String> comboNVite;
    @FXML public void GeneraCodice(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(listUtentiPartita.getItems().size()<=8) {
        if(listUtentiPartita.getItems().size()>1) {
            try {
                
                UUID uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID();
                String uniqueCode = uniqueID.toString().replaceAll("-", "").substring(0, 8);
                File file = new File(pathStatus);

                
                /**
                File file = new File(pathStatus);
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);//controlla errori legati alla lettura e scrittura del file
                String codPartita = scan.nextLine().split(" , ")[1];
                scan.close();

                //controllare univocita
                codPartita = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(codPartita)+1);

                //aggiungo al codice gli 0 non rilevanti
                int nCifre = codPartita.length();
                for(int i=0; i<lungCodicePartita-nCifre; i++) {
                    codPartita="0"+codPartita;
                }**/

                //lblCodice.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: grey;");
                txtCodice.setText(uniqueCode);

                btnGeneraCodice.setDisable(true);

                //salvo il codice corrente nel file di status
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                fw.write("codicePartita , "+uniqueCode);
                fw.close();

                //do le vite e le carte ai giocatori
                String nVite = comboNVite.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                if(nVite!=null) {
                    for(Giocatore i : giocatoriPrt) {
                        i.setVite(Integer.parseInt(nVite));
                    }
                }else {
                    for(Giocatore i : giocatoriPrt) {
                        i.setVite(nViteDefault);
                    }
                }
                
                //imposto i dati di una nuova partita
                this.prt=new Partita(uniqueCode, giocatoriPrt);
                
                //do le carte a ogni giocatore
                mazzo.mescola();
                numeroCarteAGiocatore=quanteCarteAGiocatore(prt.getElencoGiocatori().size());
                for(Giocatore g : this.prt.getElencoGiocatori()) {
                    g.setCarteMano(mazzo.pescaCarte(numeroCarteAGiocatore));
                }
                
                //salvo la partita su file.json
                SalvaPartita(this.prt);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }catch(IOException eIO) {
                System.out.println(eIO);            
            }
        }else {
            txtCodice.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");
            txtCodice.setText("Aggiungi almeno 2 giocatori");
        }
        }else {
            txtCodice.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");
            txtCodice.setText("Puoi aggiungere al massimo 8 giocatori");

        }
    }

    
    @FXML Button btnTornaAllaHome;
    //torno alla Schermata di login
    @FXML public void TornaAllaHome(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        //chiudo la finestra di di creazione della partita e torno alla finestra di login
        Stage stage = (Stage)btnTornaAllaHome.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
        
        //riapro la finestra di login
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            
            ControllerHome controller = loader.getController();         
            stage.setTitle("HOME");
            Scene interfacciaHome = new Scene(root);
            //copio le informazioni relative alla partita in corso e carico le informazioni della classifica
            controller.copiaInformazioniPartita(this.prt);
            controller.populateListView();

            stage.setScene(interfacciaHome);
            stage.setMinHeight(400);
            stage.setMinWidth(600);
            stage.show();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   

    public void populateListView() {
        
        try {
            File file = new File(pathGiocatoriRegistrati);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);           
            while(scan.hasNext()) {
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                lstGiocatoriRegistrati.getItems().add(line.trim()); 
            }
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        //metto il contenuto della listview in grassetto
        lstGiocatoriRegistrati.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
        
        //centro le scritte all'interno della listview
        lstGiocatoriRegistrati.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty || item == null) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item);
                    setAlignment(javafx.geometry.Pos.CENTER);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    private int quanteCarteAGiocatore(int numeroGiocatori) {
        if(numeroGiocatori>4) {
            return 5;
        }else if(numeroGiocatori == 2){
            return 1;
        }else {
            return numeroGiocatori;
        }
    }
    
    private void SalvaPartita(Partita partita) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<Partita> elencoPartite = new ArrayList<Partita>();
            String path="src/SalvataggioPartite.json";
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
            JsonReader jsnReader=new JsonReader(fr);

            if(jsnReader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL){
                jsnReader.beginArray();
                //carico il contenuto del file
                while(jsnReader.hasNext()) {
                    Partita p = gson.fromJson(jsnReader, Partita.class);
                    elencoPartite.add(p);
                }
                jsnReader.endArray();
                jsnReader.close();
                
                //tentativo di trasformare i bot in giocatori();
                ArrayList<Giocatore> elencoGiocatori = new ArrayList<Giocatore>();
                elencoGiocatori = partita.getElencoGiocatori();
                for(Giocatore g : elencoGiocatori) {
                    if(g instanceof Bot) {
                        ((Bot) g).setInterfaccia(null);
                    }
                }
                
                for (Partita p : elencoPartite) {
                    gson.toJson(p, Partita.class, jsnWriter);//error
                    fw.write('\n');
                }
                jsnWriter.endArray();
                jsnWriter.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

class Bot.java

```
package basic;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class Bot extends Giocatore implements Runnable,Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    GridPane interfaccia;
    Partita prt;
    final int delay = 3;//in secondi 

    public Bot(String nome, String password, int nVite, ArrayList<Carta> carte, long punteggio) {
        super(nome, nVite, carte, punteggio);
    }

    public Bot(String nome) {
        super(nome);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        giocaTurno();
    }

    public void giocaTurno(BorderPane root, Partita prt) {
        this.interfaccia = (GridPane)root.getCenter();
        this.prt=prt;
    }

    private void giocaTurno() {//metodo principale che permette di far giocare il bot e di conseguenza avanzare la partita
        //controllo se devo giocare una carta o dichiarare le prese()
        String idNodoLabel ="lblPrese";
        String idNodoBtnNuovoRound ="btnIniziaNuovoRound";
        String idNodoBtnNuovaMano ="btnIniziaNuovaMano";        
        Iterator<Node> i = interfaccia.getChildren().iterator();

        //cerco il bottone associato all'id 
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Object o = i.next();
            if(o instanceof Button) {
                Button b = (Button)o;
                if(b.getId().equals(idNodoBtnNuovoRound)&&b.isVisible()) {
                    Task<Void> t2 = taskDelay(delay);
                    new Thread(t2).start();//avvio il task per il delay
                    t2.setOnSucceeded(event2 -> {//finito il delay procedo con le operazioni
                        iniziaNuovoRound(b);
                    });
                    return;
                }else if(b.getId().equals(idNodoBtnNuovaMano)&&b.isVisible()) {
                    Task<Void> t2 = taskDelay(delay);
                    new Thread(t2).start();//avvio il task per il delay
                    t2.setOnSucceeded(event2 -> {//finito il delay procedo con le operazioni
                        iniziaNuovaMano(b);
                    });
                    return;
                } 
            }
        }
        
        //reset iteratore
        i=interfaccia.getChildren().iterator();
        
        //cerco la label associato all'id e ne controllo alcuni parametri se il ciclo prima non ha fatto return e quindi btnIniziaNuovaMano e btnIniziaNuovoRound sono visibili
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Object o = i.next();
            if(o instanceof Label) {
                Label l = (Label)o;
                if(l.getId().equals(idNodoLabel)) {
                    Task<Void> t = taskDelay(delay);
                    new Thread(t).start();//avvio il task per il delay
                    t.setOnSucceeded(event ->{//finito il delay procedo con le operazioni
                        iniziaTurno();

                        Task<Void> t1 = taskDelay(delay);
                        new Thread(t1).start();//avvio il task per il delay
                        t1.setOnSucceeded(event1 -> {//finito il delay procedo con le operazioni
                            //controllo se devo dichiarare le prese o giocare una carta
                            if(l.isVisible()) {
                                dichiaraPrese();
                            }else {
                                giocaCarta();
                            }

                            Task<Void> t2 = taskDelay(delay);
                            new Thread(t2).start();//avvio il task per il delay
                            t2.setOnSucceeded(event2 -> {//finito il delay procedo con le operazioni
                                finisciTurno();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void dichiaraPrese() {
        String idNodoFinale ="txtNumeroPrese";
        String idNodoIntermedio ="gridPaneNumeroPrese";

        Iterator<Node> i = interfaccia.getChildren().iterator();

        //cerco il nodo associato all'id e inserisco il numero di prese
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Object o = i.next();
            if(o instanceof GridPane) {
                GridPane gp = (GridPane)o;
                if(gp.getId().equals(idNodoIntermedio)) {
                    Iterator<Node> y = gp.getChildren().iterator();
                    while(y.hasNext()) {
                        o=y.next();
                        if(o instanceof TextField) {
                            TextField tf = (TextField)o;
                            if(tf.getId().equals(idNodoFinale)) {
                                //controlla giustizia numero inserito
                                Random rand = new Random();

                                //controllo che il numero di prese dichiarate sia appropriato
                                int nPrese=0;
                                for(Giocatore gio : this.prt.getElencoGiocatori()) {
                                    if(gio.getPreseDichiarate()>=0) {//controllo che prese dichiarate non abbia il valores di default
                                        nPrese+=gio.getPreseDichiarate();
                                    }
                                }

                                int n = rand.nextInt(this.carte.size()+1);
                                nPrese+=n;
                                
                                //controllo che il numero generato non vada in conflitto 
                                if(nPrese==this.carte.size()) {
                                    tf.setText(""+(n+1));
                                }else {
                                    tf.setText(""+n);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void giocaCarta() {
        String idNodo ="imgCartaMano";
        String idNodoIntermedio = "gridPaneCarteMano";
        Iterator<Node> i = interfaccia.getChildren().iterator();

        //cerco il nodo associato all'id e ne scateno l'evento
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Object o = i.next();
            if(o instanceof GridPane) {
                GridPane gp=(GridPane)o;
                if(gp.getId().equals(idNodoIntermedio)) {
                    Iterator<Node> y = gp.getChildren().iterator();
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int n = rand.nextInt(this.carte.size())+1;
                    while(y.hasNext()) {
                        o = y.next();
                        if(o instanceof ImageView) {
                            ImageView iv = (ImageView)o;
                            if(iv.getId().equals(idNodo+n)) {
                                MouseEvent mouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                                        iv.getScaleX(), iv.getScaleY(),  // Le coordinate x e y dell'evento
                                        0, 0, 
                                        null, 0, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, null
                                        );  
                                iv.fireEvent(mouseEvent);
                                return;//evito che il ciclo vada a richiamare un nuovo random generando un errore dovuto a this.carte.size()=0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void iniziaTurno() {
        String idNodo ="btnInizioTurnoGiocatore";
        scatenaNodoInterfaccia (idNodo);
    }
    
    private void finisciTurno() {
        String idNodo ="btnFineTurnoGiocatore";
        scatenaNodoInterfaccia(idNodo);

    }
    
    private void iniziaNuovoRound(Button b) {
        b.fire();
    }
    
    private void iniziaNuovaMano(Button b) {
        b.fire();
    }
    
    private void scatenaNodoInterfaccia(String idNodo) {
        Iterator<Node> i = interfaccia.getChildren().iterator();

        //cerco il bottone associato all'id e ne scateno l'evento
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Object o = i.next();
            if(o instanceof Button) {
                Button b = (Button)o;
                if(b.getId().equals(idNodo)) {  
                    b.fire();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private Task<Void> taskDelay(int secondi){
        Task<Void> slowTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // Simuliamo un'operazione lenta
                for (int i = 0; i < secondi; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // Rallenta per 3 secondi in totale
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        
        return slowTask;
    }
    
    public Giocatore getGiocatore(){
        return new Giocatore(this.nome, this.nVite, this.carte, this.punteggio);
    }

    public GridPane getInterfaccia() {
        return interfaccia;
    }

    public void setInterfaccia(GridPane interfaccia) {
        this.interfaccia = interfaccia;
    }

    public Partita getPrt() {
        return prt;
    }

    public void setPrt(Partita prt) {
        this.prt = prt;
    }
}
```

to solve it I tried to change the VM arguments but maybe I did something wrong because the same error occured:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH9qB.png)

I just want that my jsonReader works, could someone help me?

Comment: It's possible to solve this with `--add-opens`, but the more appropriate fix is to change your design so you _do not_ try to serialize GUI objects.

Comment: thanks, I change my design now it works

Comment: It is good you got your answer.  For next time, provide a [mcve] and also follow [naming conventions for method names](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at non modular JavaFX applications because you don't have to bother again with something like this.